# Feature transform-3d doesn't exist for media null

Tags: css, 3d, media-queries

The following code:

```
@media(transform-3d), (-o-transform-3d), (-ms-transform-3d), (-moz-transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d){#ls-test3d{position:absolute;left:9px;height:3px;}
```

result in wc3 validation error as:

> Feature transform-3d doesn't exist for media null ),
>   (-o-transform-3d), (-ms-transform-3d), (-moz-transform-3d),
>   (-webkit-transform-3d){#ls-test3d{position:absolute;left:9px;height:3px;}
>   }

What does its means and wrong here?

Comment: What do you expect from your code? Do you want to apply these styles if the browser supports any kind of `transform-3d`?

Comment: Perhaps link to a jsfiddle which will provide more context.

Comment: Although at face value you are attempting to pass transform-3d as the condition for a media query, which is not a valid capability. Detecting of animation support should be done in javascript.

Comment: I need to apply above code but it seems to be not working. its a wordpress plugin code

Comment: Could you provide the name of the plugin

Comment: Layerslider of wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with how you have defined the condition, the error clearly states that 'Feature transform-3d doesn't exist for media null' i.e. the @media is not set for any particular value. You need to set for what media type you are writing this condition.

For ex the below query checks for transform for all media types:

```
@media all (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d){
transition: transform .6s ease in-out; 
}
```

here I specified for all @media types, you can be specific for what type u want.